# Spring based bundle on apache karaf doesn't work

Tags: spring, maven, apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf

I am creating a spring based bundle with maven with the following command

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.camel.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=camel-archetype-spring -DarchetypeVersion=2.15.3 -DgroupId=osgiSpring -DartifactId=osgiSpring -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackage=osgiSpring
```

Then i imported this maven project into eclipse and just change the 'camel-context.xml' to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--

 Copyright 2005-2014 Red Hat, Inc.

 Red Hat licenses this file to you under the Apache License, version
 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0



    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
     implied.  See the License for the specific language governing
     permissions and limitations under the License.

    -->
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
    <from uri="file:C:\input"/>
    <to uri="file:C:\output"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>

</beans>
```

After that I built it with 'mvn package' and then I copied the generated jar into Apache Karafs' deploy folder but karaf doesn't seem to recognize this bundle.

When I run it with 'mvn:camel run' it works just fine.

It also worked with a non spring based bundle with an Activator.

Comment: Can you post the error in your log?

Comment: I would if I had one ... as I said just absolutely nothing happens after copying that jar into the deploy folder

Comment: Well, without logs, all I can suggest is to try what it say here, in the wrap deployer https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.2.x/users-guide/deployer.html

 Probably the problem is the artifact that is not the right one for karaf, yet cannot help it about which artifact should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that camel-archetype-spring generates pom.xml with just camel-maven-plugin which as you noticed allows you to run your code via 'mvn camel:run'. However, it does not generate proper OSGi manifest so Karaf won't recognise it as OSGi bundle.

**Solution**: Add maven-bundle-plugin like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

and set packaging to bundle like this:

```
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
```

You can read about other configuration options available to maven-bundle-plugin [here](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html). I suggest you check your jar file's META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file before and after you make these changes so you get the grasp of what changes there.